# Is it possible to resurrect a Documentation topic request that has apparently gone bad?

Tags: discussion, documentation

So over in the Microsoft SQL Server Documentation, one of the highest ranked requests was [Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/topic-requests/581), and in response somebody created the topic of [Truncate Table](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/4544/truncate-table#t=201608012006437900025). This marked the Indexes request as handled, but obviously does not fulfill the request at all. I was wondering what the best course of action for fixing this would be.

Is it at all possible to bring back the original request and separate the Truncate Table document so that the request could be properly fulfilled? Or would it just be easier to convert the Truncate Table document to the Indexes one?

I personally am against the idea of leaving Truncate Table as the response to the Indexes request and just creating a new Indexes request or document.

Comment: The Truncate Table example is certainly out of place as a response to the desired topic of Indexes.  Perhaps there is a topic concerning minimally logged operations (e.g. bulk loading and the like) where this example or an improved version of it would find a useful home.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would re-post the request and either delete Truncate Table or find a way to make it useful for something. The current example is not very good; I would recommend getting rid of it.

Comment: In the end, the Truncate Table topic has been deleted and a new [Index](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/4998/index#t=201608031411585020716) topic was created. While I've marked this as the answer, I'm still concerned about a few things. Like, what if the Truncate Table article was good and we wanted to keep it while attributing it to the author? Hopefully SO has good Docs tools for merging, moving, and splitting coming in the future.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage, with just a single (poor) example, I'm tempted to just edit Truncate Table to relate to Indexes, and remove the current example, then create a proper "Truncate Table" request and topic